# Pasar una variable PHP a JavaScript Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Tengo un archivo HTML donde tengo una tabla con imágenes. Quiero hacer que cuando el usuario pulse una imagen u otra inicie sesión en diferentes usuarios. Para ello he creada una función Ajax que quiero que se ejecute mediante el atributo onclick de la imagen. Mi problema es que tengo una variable *logo* que es la que identifica a cada usuario y me gustaría poder pasarla a través de la función Ajax.
Son archivos muy largos, pero un trozo del HTML sería:

```html
<table class="centro">
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        while(isset($resultado))
                        {
                            ?>
                                <td>
                                    <img class="click" src="<?php echo $resultado['logo'] ?>" onclick="my_function()"><br><br><?php echo $resultado['nombre'] ?>
                                </td>
                            <?php
                            $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <td>
                            <img width="154" src="imagenes/new.png"><br>
                            <form action="usuario.php" method="GET">
                                <input class="formulario" type="text" name="nombre" value="Introduce aquí el nombre">
                                <?php if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && empty($_POST['nombre'])) { echo "<span style='color:red;'> ¡Introduce el nombre de la nueva cuenta!</span>"; } ?> <br>
                                <input class="boton2" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Añadir usuario">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
```

Siendo **$resultado['logo']** la variable que quiero mantener.
Por otro lado la función llamada mediante *onclick*:

```javascript
<script>
        function my_function() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
                }
            };
            request.open("POST", "ajax_funcion.php", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Mientras que el archivo 'ajax_funcion.php' al cual llama la función sería:

```
<?php
    session_start();
@$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bdintegradora');
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT U.cuenta,U.nombre,U.tipo FROM usuarios U, logos L WHERE U.cuenta=L.cuenta AND U.nombre=L.nombre AND L.logo='".$resultado['logo']."'";
    $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);
    $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
    if(isset($resultado))
    {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['tipo'] = $resultado['tipo'];
        $_SESSION['logo'] = $resultado['logo'];
        header("Location:paginas/pagina.php");
    }
?>
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar, es para un proyecto de PHP, con lo que realmente de JavaScript apenas tengo conocimientos y de las funciones Ajax no había oído si quiero hablar hasta que me he puesto a investigar cómo hacer lo que quería.
Así un poco en resumen, se trata de una página donde accedes y te logeas con tu cuenta, entonces aparece una página con 2,3 o 4 iconos que hacer referencia a los usuarios que hay en dicha cuenta, ahí es donde el usuario decide con que usuario, de los disponibles en su cuenta, va a acceder a la web. Una vez en la web, aparece el icono del usuario en el índice y le saluda con su nombre (en la base de datos de MySQL tengo almacenados en la misma tabla el usuario con su logo correspondiente).
Espero que haberme explicado lo mejor posible. Muchas gracias de antemano

**NUEVOS AVANCES**
Con la ayuda de un compañero he conseguido avanzar de forma que ahora si se me garda o mantiene el valor de la variable 'logo' pero una vez se ejecuta la página 'ajax_funcion.php' no se me abre, se me queda con una especie de mensaje arriba.
El nuevo código HTML sería:

```html
<table class="centro">
                    <tr>
                        <?php
                        while(isset($resultado))
                        {
                            ?>
                                <td>
                                    <img class="click" src="<?php echo $resultado['logo'] ?>" onclick="my_function(this)"><br><br><?php echo $resultado['nombre'] ?>
                                </td>
                            <?php
                            $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
                        }
                        ?>
                        <td>
                            <img width="154" src="imagenes/new.png"><br>
                            <form action="usuario.php" method="GET">
                                <input class="formulario" type="text" name="nombre" value="Introduce aquí el nombre">
                                <?php if(isset($_POST['enviar']) && empty($_POST['nombre'])) { echo "<span style='color:red;'> ¡Introduce el nombre de la nueva cuenta!</span>"; } ?> <br>
                                <input class="boton2" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Añadir usuario">
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    <tr>
                </table>
```

Mientras que el código de la función de JavaScript:

```javascript
<script>
        function my_function(img) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
                }
            };
            const ruta=img.src.split("/")
            console.log(img);
            request.open("POST", "ajax_funcion.php", true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send("logo=imagenes/"+(ruta[ruta.length-1]));
        }
    </script>
```

Y el cogido de la página 'ajaxfuncion.php':

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['cuenta']))
    {
        header("Location:login.php");
    }

        echo $_POST['logo'];
   
    @$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','','bdintegradora');
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    $sql = "SELECT U.cuenta,U.nombre,U.tipo FROM usuarios U, logos L WHERE U.cuenta=L.cuenta AND U.nombre=L.nombre AND L.logo='".$_POST['logo']."'";
    $consulta = $conexion->query($sql);
    $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc();
    if(isset($resultado))
    {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado['nombre'];
        $_SESSION['tipo'] = $resultado['tipo'];
        $_SESSION['logo'] = $_POST['logo'];
        header("Location:paginas/pagina.php");
    }
?>
```

Adjunto una foto del mensaje donde se puede apreciar cómo me devuelve el código de la página 'paginas/netflix.php'
[image: Imágen del]

El caso es que ahora si me guarda la variable pero la página que se debería abrir una vez se ejecuta 'ajaxfuncion.php' no se abre, me muestra el código de dicha página en forma de mensaje.
Muchas gracias espero que podáis ayudarme

Comment: Quieres pasar **$resultado['logo']** a traves del metodo OnClick en **my_function()** ???

Comment: Si, ese era mi principal problema, he conseguido solucionar eso, ahora cuando se ejecuta la pagina 'ajaxfuncion.php' deberia a través de 'header:Location' de PHP redirigir al usuario a otra página, pero en este caso me muestra el codigo de la pagina. Tienes todos los detalles en la descripción